# How to parse an XML file using ElementTree in Python 2.6

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have an XML file named Enums.txt like this:

```
<Enums>
    <Enum name = "abc">
        <Item>Inactive</Item>
        <Item>Active</Item>
    </Enum>
    <Enum name = "xyz">
        <Item>Blocked</Item>
        <Item>Halted</Item>
    </Enum>
    <Enum name = "pqr">
        <Item>NONE</Item>
        <Item>PASS</Item>
        <Item>BLOCK</Item>
    </Enum>
</Enums>
```

When I run "python parseXml.py abc,pqr" in command line tags inside abc and pqr should be removed and the modified file should be written to a new file.

Following is my parseXml.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import sys
import commands

tree = ElementTree.parse('Enums.txt')
wanted=sys.argv[1]
wantedSet=set(wanted.strip().split(','))

for enum in root.findall('Enum'):
    name=enum.get('name')
    if name not in wantedSet:
        for child in list(enum):
            enum.remove(child)
tree.write('Enums_new.txt')
```

But it gives the following syntax error.

```
File "parseXml.py", line 5, in <module>
    tree = ElementTree.parse('Enums.txt')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 862, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 586, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1245, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 0
```

Can anybody help me to correct this error?

Comment: You should include the error you are getting.

Comment: Sorry.. This is the error:File "parseXml.py", line 5, in <module>
    tree = ElementTree.parse('Enums.txt')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 862, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 586, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1245, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: syntax error: line 1, column 0

Comment: Well it says your `Enums.txt` is not a valid xml, check using some online validator, if the xml is really valid or not.

Comment: I validated.. it's a correct XML file. I guess it's that the Element tree module is not compatible with my python version or something.

Comment: @AnandSKumar file should be named using the .xml extension. That was the problem. Thanks for the help :)